# Accessing Microsoft SQL DB from Android App

Tags: android, sql

I am trying to access Microsoft SQL Database through Android App.

I have extracted data from mysql using JSON on PHP (using help of http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) as HTTP request.

I am not sure how to go about doing it for Microsoft SQL DB. Can somebody guide me to extract data from microsoft SQL? This is running IIS and need to connect via ASP.NET?

Thanks!

Comment: its about php then? you access your SQL DB using your php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make certain changes in api made in php to connect to ms SQL. Refer this [link](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/connect_mssql_database.php). You can use the same api call what you are doing currently in android to fetch data.

There is other option you can create the api in .net and call that api in android. Refer this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/how-to-create-web-api-in-Asp-Net-mvc/)

Comment: Fahim: Thanks for quick reply. This is IIS server I don't have PHP access here. so option is ASP.net? can I get it through HTTP request?

Comment: Then you have to create an api in asp.net and that can be called using http request. Added the link to create api in asp.net

Comment: Accept my answer if it has helped u

Comment: Doesn't have to be ASP.NET, I would go with a WCF web service.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396